# can not load file in code Java after maven task configuration

Tags: java, maven

I have module Java and I would like to make my code:

```
public class ParserProperties {

    private Properties properties;

    public static void main(String[] obj) throws IOException {
        ParserProperties parserProperties = new ParserProperties();
        parserProperties.make();
    }

    public void make() {
        try {
            properties = ParserProperties.read("environment.properties");
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("server.address"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Properties read(String filePath) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = null;
        FileInputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(is);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Fetch the file environment.properties depending on the environment on which it will be built .

Locally and on the test server retrieves the file environment.test.properties
and the production of environment.prod.properties.

In Java Resource I have 3 files:

```
environment.properties
environment.test.properties
environment.prod.properties
```

My pom.xml look like this:

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build-dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <config.name>environment.test.properties</config.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>build-prod</id>
            <properties>
                <config.name>environment.prod.properties</config.name>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/environment.properties"/>
                                <copy file="src/main/resources/${config.name}" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/environment.properties"/>
                                <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/environment.test.properties"/>
                                <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/environment.prod.properties"/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have problem becouse throws nullPointerException in load file